# Crossed-random effects model: linear heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, crossed-random-effects

we conducted a study in which two groups from different populations (both n = 25) were instructed to rate the symmetry (visual analogue scales, 0 to 100) of 50 different faces in randomised order each. As an independent variable we measured the objective symmetry of these faces (asymmetry-index, theoretically 0 to +∞, in our sample: 1.3 to 5.1). We want to investigate whether symmetry ratings are predicted by the objective asymmetry-index and the group.

We calculated following crossed-random effects model:

```
m <- sym_rating.z ~ 1  + asym_index.z*group + (1 + asym_index.z| participant) + (1| Face)
fit <- lmer( m, data = df, REML = TRUE, lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
summary(fit)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: m
   Data: df
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

REML criterion at convergence: 21615.1

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9778 -0.6896  0.0161  0.6745  3.1950 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participant (Intercept) 126.9    11.265  
 Face        (Intercept)  71.1     8.432  
 Residual                299.6    17.309  
Number of obs: 2500, groups:  participant, 50; Face, 50

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        22.2886     4.9359   81.7382   4.516 2.10e-05 ***
asym_index         -9.0054     1.9049   55.7453  -4.728 1.59e-05 ***
group              -6.5219     3.9643  104.4264  -1.645    0.103    
asym_index:group    0.7442     1.0231 2400.0000   0.727    0.467    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) asym_n group 
asym_index  -0.851              
group       -0.402  0.153       
asym_ndx:gr  0.228 -0.269 -0.569
```

When we looked at the residuals, we found that the assumption of normal distribution was satisfied, but the residual plot showed the following pattern:

[image: Conditional studentized residuals vs. fitted values]

As we got a negative linear trend in the residuals as a result, we included the order of the presentations as a further predictor. Even though we found a significant influence of the order we still get the heteroscedastic negative linear residuals.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve our problem?

Comment: Your issue is that your dependent variable is bounded by 0 and 100. You need to use a GLMM with an appropriate distribution family.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use standardized residuals (or studentized, depends on your own) instead of the using raw values. Then you should check distribution of residuals on normality. And only after that you should evaluate heteroscedastic pattern of your model.

Comment: The plot clearly shows pearson residuals and not raw residuals.

Comment: @Gregory Thank you for your answer. I checked again and the residuals satisfy the assumption of normality. I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, but you should make “studentized residuals - fitted values” plot, and only after that look at the possible homogeneity. Pearson residuals are not studentized residuals, we could exactly see this on your plot.

Comment: Unfortunately also the studentized residuals show the same pattern. I edited the question with the studentized residuals.

Comment: I remember, the range was from -40 to 40, now there is from -3 to 3. And if your residuals are normally distributed, then you should check homogeneity. It is clear from the plot that this assumption is not satisfied. You could use Newey-West matrix instead of simple covariance matrix, although, sample volume is not so big, but it is okay I suggest.

Comment: @GregoryStelmashenko What are you talking about? OP has data that is bounded by 0 and 100. The only sensible approach here is using a model that takes this into account, e.g., a GLMM.